# How to write Ext.Loader.setPath()?

Tags: plugins, sencha-touch-2

I create one sencha touch project using sencha cmd.  I have one plugin call ux.plugin.MyPlug and I put 'ux' under the same directory of 'touch'. In app.js, I add   Ext.Loader.setPath('ux', 'ux'). When I run ' sencha app build testing', I get error 'c2008 requirement had no matching files ..ux.plugin.Myplug..', how to inlcude ux",thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need SetPath for thing like plugin,  adding to requres is enough.